# Xcode 4 keyboard shortcut to switch build target destination

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode4, ios-simulator, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Xcode 4 to switch the build target destination; that is, to switch from simulator to device and vice versa?

Answer (score 32):

There is, is called Destination>select next destination.  Go in the prefs in xcode and then  in the key bindings tab, search for that, it will show what key it is set at.

For me, is <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> and <kbd>[</kbd> to switch. Is quite useful, saves a few seconds.

Answer (score 15):

In Xcode 4.6, the shortcut is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd>

Answer (score 14):

You can use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>]</kbd> to select scheme, or use <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + [alt] <kbd>[</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>cmd</kbd> + [alt] <kbd>]</kbd> to select product
Or you can just search in the preference panel of key bindings for more information

Answer (score 6):

You can write applescript and bind it to some hotkey (using FastScripts for example - free up to ten bindings).
Next script will click for you on your scheme button in the Xcode toolbar:

```
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Xcode"
        click ((pop up buttons of list 1 of group 2 of tool bar 1 of front window) whose description is "Active Run Destination")
    end tell
end tell
```

then you can just use Up/Down to switch destination.
Note that you need to enable access for assistive devices under the SystemPreferences -> Accessibility

Answer (score 4):

You can go to the edit scheme menu with <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd><</kbd> which is actually <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd>

You should know

- Build: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>
- Run: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
- Test: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>
- Profile: <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>
- Analyze: <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

But there isn't a command just to switch between the iPhone simulator, iPad simulator, and all of your external.

Comment: Edit scheme menu is `cmd + shift + <`

Answer (score 4):

I have a slightly different problem but it might help you as well.
I have only one physical device which always stays at the top.
Its super simple to select top list device as a target.

Do:

1. pops up the list for target devices

   <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>
2. takes you to the first device

   <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>UPARROW</kbd>
3. selects that device

   <kbd>SPACE</kbd>

Apple Script goes:

```
tell application "Xcode" to activate


tell application "System Events"
 tell process "Xcode"
    keystroke "0" using {control down, shift down}
    delay 0.55
    keystroke (ASCII character 29)
    delay 0.55
    keystroke (ASCII character 30) using command down
    delay 0.55
    keystroke (ASCII character 32)
    delay 0.55
    keystroke "r" using command down
 end tell
end tell
```

Answer (score 2):

Riffing on off Comradsky, the answer is then:

<kbd>Cmd</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> then  <kbd>Tab</kbd> then <kbd>Up</kbd>/<kbd>Down</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

You can also option-click on the scheme in the title bar to directly open the settings for the scheme (whereas a normal click opens the context menu that displays a list of all the schemes).

Answer (score 0):

#### Show Destinations

To bring up the list of destinations use ⤵︎

<kbd>^</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>